# Unequally right-censored survival analysis

Tags: survival, small-sample, censoring

I'm trying to do a survival analysis and I want to know how to handle unequal right-censorship.

Essentially, people enter the trial at different ages and exit either at death or at the end of the trial. I want to know how to analyze the data against standard actuarial expectations: do those in the trial tend to live longer or shorter than those in the general population?

For each person who dies during the trial, I can find their percentile among the general population: if they were 61 when entering the trial and died at 65, they outlived ~6% of the population of 61-year-olds and were survived by ~93% who lived to be 66. For those still alive at the end of the trial I can do the same: a 63-year-old entering the trial and exiting at trial completion at 77 has outlived ~32% of the 63-year-old population but may outlive more still.

What analysis do I do and how can I interpret the results?

For my particular sample, there is no dropout and the sample size is small, but it's not critical to address either of these features.

Comment: Have you looked into models with stochastic censoring cut-offs, like [Lagakos 1976](https://doi.org/10.2307/2529744) or [Nelson 1977](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-4076(77)90003-3)?

Comment: @Durden Lagakos 1976 doesn't seem relevant -- it's mainly about having an auxiliary variable (tumor progression is their example) as an alternative for censored data -- but Nelson 1974/1977 seems interesting. I'm looking it up now, thanks!

Comment: This seems like a 2 step problem. The first step is to estimate the survival distribution in your trial, which can be done by adapting the R code `plot(survfit(Surv(start, stop, event)~1, data=heart))` using the `survival` package. The second step is to get the estimated survival curves from the general population and then make comparisons.